# Display Managed Metadata terms in order in list (Multiple Values)?

Tags: managed-metadata

How can I keep the terms in the same order regardless of the order they were entered when the item was created?

Consider this list:

[image]

I want the color order to always be the same... e.g.

```
John     Red;Green;

Julie    Red;Green;

Tim      Red;
```